# How to encode a span in a text sequence by tf.keras.layers.LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, tf.keras

I am new to `tf.keras` functional API. I am now building a model which encodes certain span of words in a sentence sequence by layers of LSTM. For example, the input is: `[None, max_sent_len, word_embedding_dim]`, span: `[2, 5]` should pass the word of `index[2,3,4]` into a LSTM layer and output the last hidden layer. Is there any function in `tf.keras` that can build this easily? Or should I use low level tensorflow to build this?

Comment: Maybe you need [Masking layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Masking).

Comment: Thanks. I tried masking layer with a multiply layer that does element-wise multiplication to zero out the timestep I do not want. It seems to work!